# Creating a Function that selects individual items out of an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have a question, and I am very new to JS. I want to create a function that selects items out of an Array on click. I have been able to create this, however it doesn't seem that the loop is working correctly. It selects the whole array as opposed to single items, even though I have specified the conditions of the loop to start from [0] and increment by 1 until the length of the array...

Here is what I have:

```
    <button onclick=PickNum()>Pick</button>
<br />
<h1 id="cal1"></h1>
<script>

    function PickNum() {
        var arnum = [ " 1 ", " 2 ", " 3 ", " 4 " ];
        var loopz;
        var wrote = "";
        for (loopz = 0; loopz < arnum.length; loopz++) {
            wrote+= arnum[loopz];
        }
        document.getElementById('cal1').innerHTML+= wrote;

        }
    document.write(typeof arnum[loopz]);
</script>
```

Thanks all

Comment: The loop *is* working as you specified: looping to the end, and creating "wrote" with all the items of the array. What do you want specifically?

Comment: *"I want to create a function that selects items out of an Array"* "Selects" items how? Your current code doesn't do any filtering at all, you're just grabbing each element. It's not clear what you want it to do instead...

Comment: Do you want to join all the array elements into one string? (That's what's happening.) Or do you want to select one of the array elements and write that to `innerHTML`? Also, `arnum` is out of scope at `typeof arnum[loopz]`.

Comment: Yes, sorry if the question was unclear. You the result of the click was "1234" with each click and I wanted it to just be "1" then "2" then "3" with each click. I understand it it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not exactly clear, but judging by what you said ("increment by 1 until the length of the array...") I believe that you want to print one number of the array for each click:

```
var arnum = [ " 1 ", " 2 ", " 3 ", " 4 " ];
var loopz = 0;
function PickNum() {
    document.getElementById('cal1').innerHTML= arnum[loopz];
    if(loopz < arnum.length -1){
        loopz++; 
    } else {
        loopz = 0;
    };
}
```

Here's the example: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/enj4732o/

Comment: Is it not possible to do this with the method I have? Or is it just not the best way to go about it? Just curious because I'm learning...

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question, but if you are talking about your original code, this is the problem: you have a for-loop that goes from 0 to array.length. In that loop, you add an array value to "wrote". When the loop finishes, "wrote" is pretty much equal to the original array. Then, when you use innerHTML to print "wrote", you print all the values in each button click.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var index = 0;
var arnum = [" 1 ", " 2 ", " 3 ", " 4 "];

function PickNum() {

  console.log(arnum[index]);
  index++;
  if (index == arnum.length) {
    index = 0;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick=PickNum()>Pick</button>

<h1 id="cal1"></h1>
```